# How do I stop an Apps Script from running?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I keep getting emails that say the following, line after line:

> 11/24/12 7:06 PM   timeDriven  Unable to find sheet: FormEmailer (line 656)    time-based  11/24/12 7:06 PM

I want to stop these emails and apparently a script "Copy of FormEmailer" is running. I have deleted the worksheet that was using it, and I can't get it to stop running. I don't want these emails anymore and don't know how to stop it.

Answer (score 4):

Basically a scheduled trigger is continuing to run.

Is there a link in the emails that lets you see all the Triggers? That should list the triggers and you should be able to delete them there. I haven't seen one in a while and forget all the details.

If not, then the more manual way to do it is -

1. Go to http://script.google.com
2. Click on Start Scripting button
3. Pick the Blank Project template
4. In the editor menu, go to Resources -> All Your Triggers
5. There should see "timeDriven" and you should be able to delete it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The "All Your Triggers" menu option is now under the Edit tab, not Resources.

Comment: In addition to the steps listed in this answer, one more thing I needed to do was re-enable the Email Forwarder, go to a Google Sheets doc, select Add-ons tab menu, navigate to the Email Forwarder add-on settings, and remove all triggers from there as well. I then removed the add-on again.

Answer (score 1):

View -> Executions
Then mouse over the running task, click the triple dot and click 'Terminate'.